# I cant start React project because node_models files missing but they exist

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, missing-data

I have been trying all day to fix this that I cant use `clean-tag` or `normalize-wheel` in my Reactjs project.
I have deleted NODE_MODULES and package-lock.json and done NPM INSTALL. I have created a new NPX create-react-app project imputing my source code and package.json.

As the image show The `import normalizeWheel from "normalize-wheel";` is missing a file but Nr2 on the image say no, NR3 on the image also show the Component can be found.

`normalize-wheel` dont need Dev Dependencies Please advice?

[image]

**UPDATE**
Showing where `normalize-wheel` NODE_MODULE is located

[image]

**UPDATE**

Created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-use-styled-components-3hmkw?file=/src/masonry/Text.js)  with the same problem

Comment: can you show please node_modules where normalize-wheel is located

Comment: It ask for typescript types, not the module, try to run: 

`npm install @types/normalize-wheel --save-dev`

Comment: Updated my Q with normalize-wheel node_modules location

Comment: @AnnaVlasenko  I have tried that but get` npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnormalize-wheel - Not found`

Comment: These screenshots add nothing in the way of information to your question, they're just black and blurry. Can you explain using plain text?

Comment: @tadman this images are 1920x1080 super sharp

Comment: In the question they're nowhere near that big. Just use text. Text can be used to reproduce the problem. These images do nothing but create frustration.

Comment: @tadman I dont know why you cant see the images but I appreciate your help

Comment: This isn't about me personally, it's about images in general. They are completely useless to people who use screen readers, and even if you can see what's in them, they're zero help when trying to reproduce the problem, you'll have to type in everything all over again. You have the text in a form that can be copy-pasted. Just do that.

Comment: Created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cant-use-styled-components-3hmkw?file=/src/masonry/Text.js) with this problem showing that `clean-tag` is not working